# Creating authentication API on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm creating a multiplayer game based on unity engine, and i want to expose and api using Ruby on rails for the registration and authenticating users while doing usual operations like sign in/up, and my function like create room - which will be stored in db as an entry-

These simple operations i want the api to handle it, **I'm not just asking about a tutorial to make authentication for user, i want someone to explain to be how my API mechanism will be, i will authenticate users based on tokens**, as i guess, is that right?

If it's right, can anyone give me a simple steps to follow or a useful tutorial to my case, as I've searched a lot especially when "devise" is no longer supporting authentication, and for my little knowledge i don't think devise will help me in sign in operations as it works with the existence of a model not an api.

I hope i have made my points, waiting for your help : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) with [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication)

### Steps:

1. Install `devise` an create your authenticatable model with `devise` gem.

   ```
   rails generate devise MODEL
   ```
2. Add `acts_as_token_authenticatable` to MODEL.

   If you want to authenticate the `User` (MODEL), you need to add the following code:

   **/your_app/app/models/user.rb**

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as_token_authenticatable

     # Note: you can include any module you want. If available,
     # token authentication will be performed before any other
     # Devise authentication method.
     #
     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   end
   ```
3. Add routes and controllers

   **/your_app/app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb**

   ```
   class Api::BaseController < ActionController::Base
     self.responder = ApiResponder # Ignore this, just for now.
     respond_to :json
   end
   ```

   > All your API controllers need to inherit from base controller

   **/your_app/app/controllers/api/login_attempts_controller.rb**

   ```
   class Api::LoginAttemptsController < Api::BaseController
     def create
       respond_with Api::LoginAttempt.new(params[:email], params[:password])
     rescue
       render nothing: true, status: 401
     end
   end
   ```

   **/your_app/app/models/api/login_attempt.rb**

   ```
   class Api::LoginAttempt
     include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
     attr_accessor :uid, :token

     def initialize(_email, _password)
       user = MobileUser.where(email: _email).first
       raise 'invalid_password' unless user.valid_password? _password
       self.uid = user.email
       self.token = user.authentication_token
     end

     def attributes
       { uid: nil, token: nil }
     end
   end
   ```

   > You need the `LoginAttemptsController` (Call it whatever you want) to sign in the user. If the given `password` and `email` matches you will get a `uid` and `token` to authorize user's future requests.

   **/your_app/app/controllers/api/bills_controller.rb**

   ```
   class Api::BillsController < Api::BaseController
     acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

     def show
       respond_with bill
     end

     private

     def bill
       @bill ||= Bill.find(params[:id])
     end
   end
   ```

   > `BillsController` it's just a controller to access with an authenticated request. As you can see, you need to add `acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User` to protect the controller of unauthorized requests.

   **/your_app/config/routes.rb**

   ```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
       resources :login_attempts, only: [:create]
       resources :bills, only: [:show]
     end
   end
   ```

### Flow:

1. Create an `User` instance: `User.create!(email: "leandro@example.com")`. This will create a new user with `authentication_token: "_-7CtsAxPE5SsdsfzMkY"`

   > You can create the user using the api. I don't do this here.
2. Sign in performing a `POST` request to `/api/login_attempts` with the user's email and password.

   [image]
3. Perform an authorized request: `GET /api/bills/:id` passing the headers:

   [image]

On this example I've used:

- [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)
- [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) with a [custom responder](https://github.com/platanus/potassium/blob/master/lib/potassium/assets/api/responder.rb)

**/your_app/app/serializers/bill_serializer.rb**

```
class BillSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :created_at, :amount
end
```

Comment: I know devise and i worked on before they delete authentication, but i got lost in it this time, i said up, i don't understand how to match devise with my functionality

Comment: I've update my answer with flow and implementation example. It's no my intention to give you a working example. I want to give you a "big picture". If you have doubts you need to read more in the simple_token_authentication's gem docs and maybe then, ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will return once i've a question @Leantraxxx

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer satisfy your current cuestion: "i want someone to explain to be how my API mechanism will be, i will authenticate users based on tokens" please, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Doorkeeper is a good alternative for api auth. Their readme is basically a tutorial for how to get set up: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper